# Where I should declare and/or inmplement of my custom ResultCommand?

Tags: java

I should return custom object as a function result:

```
class ConvertCommand  implement AbstractCommand {
    public ResultCommand startConvert(){
       return new ResultCommand(true, str);
    }
}
```

And I have an interface of this class:

```
interface AbstractCommand{
    public ResultCommand startConvert()   
}
```

Where I should declare and/or inmplement ResultCommand:

1. In ConvertCommand.java as inner class?
2. In new file
3. In interface AbstractCommand

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the overall structure. The list of possibilities mentioned by you is, as far as I can see, complete. So let's go through them one by one.

#### Inner Class in `ConvertCommand`

In case `ResultCommand` needs to access fields from `ConvertCommand`, or otherwise has a very close relationship to `ConvertCommand`, this is a good option.

#### In a new file

In case from an outside view `ResultCommand` is an `AbstractCommand` like any other, this is the best solution.

#### Inside `interface AbstractCommand`

This could be a good solution in case `AbstractCommand` is providing instances of `ResultCommand` in fields or `static` methods.

Comment: 1. Inner Class in ConvertCommand
But everywhere I should return **ConvertCommand.ResultCommand** not **ResultCommand**. And an interface will keep detailes of the  ConvertCommand implement ... ((

Comment: Do you need to know that the `ResultCommand` is a `ResultCommand`? Or couldn't you use the ADT `AbstractCommand` instead?

Comment: I need to know that result is a ResultCommand type. My task is replace (in a single function) *String* return type with ResultCommand type (*String + Code*). Logically it should be as inner class, but I dont understand how resolve it in interface.

Comment: That you need to write `ConvertCommand.ResultCommand` can be simplified with a corresponding `import` statement. You cannot only `import` members of a `package`, but also members of a type like `class`, `interface` or `enum`. `import mypackage.ConvertCommand.ResultCommand;` should work.